# I am trying to connect to a db

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to connect to a db but I keep getting an error that pops up every chance I get to change the db or connection string . I am currently using php mysqli and wamp will not show any error with the connection itself .

calc.php:

```
class Login {   
var $con;
function __construct($con){
    $this->con = $con;
}
function try_connecting(){
    $connecting = true;
    if($connecting){
        if(!$this->con){
            die ("Could not connect") . $this->con->connect_errno;
        } else {
            echo "connected";
        }
        } else {
        return $connecting;
    }
}   
function try_login(){
    if(try_connecting()){
        $q = "SELECT username, password FROM persons WHERE username = " . $_POST["username"] . " AND password = " .  $_POST['pwd'];
        $rows = $this->con->num_rows;   
        if($rows == 1){
            echo "true";
        } else {
            echo "not user";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the test.php:

```
    <?php
        include("calc.php");

        $u = $_POST['username'];
        $p = $_POST['pwd'];
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rdb");
        $form = new Login($con);
        $form->try_connecting();
        $form->try_login();
    ?>
```

> connection string error Unknown database

Comment: In the test.php file

Comment: Are you sure the database `rdb` exists?

Comment: P.S. Please see: http://bobby-tables.com.  I don't think you want me logging in with a username of `'admin'; -- ` and a blank password ;-)

Comment: Well... to start with, your try_connecting() function doesn't do anything and serves no purpose, you should just validate the argument that's passed to the constructor instead of checking it every time you query. Also,  you never actually *run* the query, you just build a string with the query in it. You need to call mysqli_query() somewhere. You're also not validating input, so you're susceptible to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements when building a query with user input.

Comment: your error suggests a problem with `mysqli_connect()`. Are your login credentials correct? Is `rdb` the name of your database?

Comment: Yes the database exists but I am learning this slowly but cannot get the db to connect

Comment: It did not. I am trying to connect to the db and it doesn't work

Comment: It might have to do with the try_login function since it isn't acutally doing anything like the query . But it should not give me an error as to the database exists ---

Comment: I did not know that . sorry :)

Comment: Try to create the simplest form of the issue. `Login` fails to create, `try_connecting` fails, or  `try_login` fails. Also your query in `try_login` has issues.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to run this query

```
$q = "SELECT username, password FROM persons WHERE username = " . $_POST["username"] . " AND password = " .  $_POST['pwd'];
$rows = $this->con->num_rows;
```

Try to add

```
$this->con->query($q)
```

between the lines above

Comment: Gotta read the question a second time `I am trying to connect to a db `.. Also that query has **many** issues and **should not** be used. There is a < %5 chance this query works and if so the form sending the data is very flawed.